# WCF service to handle Authentication and Roles

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, authorization, roleprovider

I am trying to create a simple WCF service to handle various security scenarios, but am not really sure where to begin.

The WCF service will be hosted on IIS (most likely). It needs to be accessible by both authenticated active directory users and non-authenticated users (anonymous/external). I need to be able to access various methods for both types, though the authenticated users should have access to additional methods.

I would like to be able to check HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated (I assume this would be the easiest way to determine which type of user - or would it be ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity) and access a roles database. The service will be accessed by both a .net 4.0 website (not webforms app and not mvc) and other external sources that may or may not be .net (java app or java web site, for instance).

I am unclear as to where to begin. What type of binding(s), transport(s), security mode(s). Can I use a membership/roles provider (SimpleMembership or the older asp.net membership) with the service?

If I want to have different types of anonymous users, do they need to be mapped to a specific active directory users for different roles or can I also include some sort of username/password to authenticate?

I also need to be able to use impersonation, so that assuming the correct rights, actions performed by one user can appear as if done by another.

I have been looking at various options and getting confused. ADFS, WIF, Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll, ACS 2.0, etc.

Not sure what is best, what is overkill, what will and will not meet the needs, what will be relatively easy to implement. Use SSL or not, and if so, how to setup both the service web.config as well as the client web.config

I know this a lot to ask, but at least if I get pointed in the right direction, I can stop looking at solutions that will not work or are overly complex and focus on the right solution(s).